# Consumo de todo espaço dinamicamente alocado no hyper-v com freebsd

Tags: hyper-v

Usamos na empresa Windows 2012 R2 com Hyper-V e hospedamos pfSense nele além de outros SOs.

Com o pfSense, ele consome o tamanho máximo do disponível no HD do Windows 2012, mas o espaço real é pequeno.

Com outros sistemas, que também são máquinas virtuais com espaço dinamicamente alocado isso não acontece.

Saberiam informar o que poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo isso se da ao fato do tipo de disco que escolheram na hora de criar o servidor.
Veja, o Hyper-V te da 3 opções fixo, dinâmico e diferencial.

1. **Fixo**
   Neste formato ele já vai alocar todo espaço informado do HD do Host.
2. **Dinâmico**
   Aqui ele vai allocando o espaço conforme a sua VM vai crescendo.
3. **Diferencial**
   Neste é necessário já ter um arquivo de disco que chamamos de pai, o pai não terá modificações, tudo que você fizer de novo será criado em um novo arquivo. (Usado mais para laboratórios, por exemplo, você quer montar um lab com 3 windows server, para ocupar menos espaço cria um arquivo só com o S.O. instalado e ele será seu disco pai, então crie 3 VM com tipo de disco diferencial e aponte para o pai, assim você terá somente o consumo de 1 SO no lugar de 3.

No seu caso esse PfSense foi montado utilizando o fixo, o que é normal, já que o fixo oferece mais performance que os outros.
Para saber mais sobre o assunto da uma olhada nesse [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yungchou/2013/01/23/hyper-v-virtual-hard-disk-vhd-operations-explained/).

Existe modos de diminuir(shrink) o tamanho do disco, mas você teria que primeiro entrar na VM, diminuir o tamanho do disco lá dentro (no windows feito pelo "Gerenciador de Discos" e no linux poderia ser feito pelo Gparted") e depois Editar o disco pelo Hyper-V usando o shrink. Este [link](https://devinknightsql.com/2014/06/19/reducing-the-disk-size-of-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine/) mostra com imagens como pode ser feito.
**Mas tenha muito cuidado, porque ao diminuir o tamanho do disco você pode acabar perdendo alguma informação e corromper o mesmo**

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta. ajudou bastante

Comment: @cpdtexto que bom que lhe ajudou. Se a resposta lhe foi útil poderia, por gentileza, considerar em marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com esta mesma dúvida?